# Apache Reverse Proxy for two web applications: One on localhost another on remote machine

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I've got two web applications: Jira and Mercurial. They used to be on the same server `Dual Host` but I've since moved Mercurial to `Mercurial Host`. Jira is still hosted on `Dual Host`.

`Dual Host` has an `Apache 2.2.22` server which used to host Mercurial but will now serve as the reverse proxy.

On my domain server, I've set up `jira` to point to `Dual Host`'s IP and `mercurial` to point to `Mercurial Host`'s IP.

People used to access Jira by going to `http://dualhost:4040/` and Mercurial by going to `http://dualhost/`.

I've set up a reverse proxy to proxy requests for `http://dualhost/` to `http://mercurial/` (so that existing links to commits in various places). This is working fine with the configuration below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dualhost
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://mercurial:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://mercurial:80/
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I wanted to proxy requests for `http://jira` to `http://dualhost:4040` but I keep getting proxied to Mercurial.

The reason for this is that I want to move Jira to a new server at a later date and the sooner the URL is 'correct' the better.

I've set that rule to:

```
<VirtualHost jira:80>
    ServerName jira
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4040/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4040/
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm looking at the [Apache 2.2](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html) documentation and this looks like it should work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<VirtualHost *:80>` in your `jira` virtualhost configuration.

Virtualhost matching is order-sensitive, so if a `<VirtualHost *:80>` comes before a `<VirtualHost jira:80>`, the second will never match. This is also true if you're using multiple distinct `conf.d/*.conf` files, since apache loads those files in alphabetical order.

From your example one could assume you'd use files named `conf.d/dualhost.conf` and `conf.d/jira.conf`. Since `dualhost` comes alphabetically before `jira`, the second would never match.

Comment: I've put them both on the same file to make sure jira is loaded first but still no joy.

Comment: Did you try the `<VirtualHost *:80>` option in the jira virtualhost?

Comment: I did. That makes everything go to jira instead.

Comment: Can you post how you're calling the jira/dualhost URLs? The `ServerName` directive must match precisely the hostname you use in your URLs, are you using an IP address (http://192.168.1.3/) or an FQDN (`jira.example.com`)? If you have more than one hostname for a service you can add several `ServerAlias` directives in the corresponding `VirtualHost` configuration, if any of them match, that `VirtualHost` will be used to service the request.

Comment: `ServerName` is `jira` and the URL is `http://jira`, the domain is served from my local DNS.

Comment: Adding jira as an alias to 127.0.0.1 to `/etc/hosts` made it work... for some reason? Thanks for the help.